# Bokeh plot with drop down button

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, bokeh

I have a csv file with a large number of columns. I've gotten to a point where I can add multiple columns on the same plot. 
What I have so far: -

```
import pandas
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

df=pandas.read_csv("finalMergedv1.csv")

p=figure(plot_width=600,plot_height=400,tools='pan,resize')

p.title="Some Title"
p.title.text_color="Gray"
p.title.text_font="arial"
p.title.text_font_style="bold"
p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color=None
p.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color=None
p.xaxis.axis_label="x Axis Title"
p.yaxis.axis_label="Column header"               

p.circle(df[df.columns[0]],df[df.columns[1]],size=10, color="Black")
p.circle(df[df.columns[0]],df[df.columns[2]],size=5, color="Coral")
p.circle(df[df.columns[0]],df[df.columns[3]],size=7, color="Gray")
output_file("Example.html")
show(p)
```

[image]

I would like to add a drop down widget to be able to select a specific column and view that specific one. The second part would be to change the y_axis_label based on the header of the column selected to view. I'm working with a dataframe thats about 50 -100 columns, so would really appreciate it if someone can tell me there is a better way to visualize that data other than bokeh. I have tried plotly, but would prefer other solutions.

Comment: You can certainly add a dropdown to select columns with Bokeh. You can either use [`CustomJS` callbacks](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html) with standalone (no server) documents for things like sliders or dropdowns. Or you canuse the Bokeh server to create sophisticated [visualization apps](https://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/crossfilter) More information about what you want to do with these plots and apps is needed to offer additional guidance.

Comment: I'm just looking for something very basic, either slide or dropdown would work. X axis is fixed (which is the first col in the csv file), the rest of the columns are plotted as y and added to the drop down menu.